# Unable to insert decimal to sql server table through c# code

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding-error

I'm not able to insert decimal values into Sql Server table.

What i'm trying to do is self explanatory through these lines of code:

```
long fileSizeInBytes = ComponentUploadControl.FileContent.Length;
Decimal fileSizeInMB = Convert.ToDecimal(fileSizeInBytes) / (1024.0m * 1024.0m);
Decimal fileSizeInMBRounded = Math.Round(fileSizeInMB, 2);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fileSize", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = fileSizeInMBRounded;
```

The value that is getting inserted into database is stripped of the decimal places. To be more specific if the fileSizeInMBRounded  is 11.73, the value that is getting inserted into database is 11,00

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Why not simply store fileSizeInBytes out of interest?

Comment: The mistake is in the stored procedure i was specifying the parameter type as simply decimal instead it should be decimal(18,2). Any ways now it works like a charm after i corrected the mistake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suspicion is that your decimal field is set up wrong in SQL.  What you want is a `decimal(18,2)` field which allows for 2 decimal places.  My suspicion is that you declared the field as `decimal(18,0)` (the default), which does not allow for any decimal places.

If you can use SQL Server Profiler to verify the contents of the INSERT going to your DB, it would be easier for you to determine whether a problem like this is due to your code or something on the SQL server.

Comment: Here is the mistake when i was inserting the data using the stored procedure,Create procedure [dbo].[NewComponentInsertion] (@componentName varchar(max), @fileSize decimal, @filePath varchar(max), @price decimal, @description varchar(max), @totalDownloads int, @disableFlag int) as insert into [dbo].[Components]([Component Name], [Size (in MB)],[Total Downloads], [FilePath], [Price (in SEK)], Description, DisableFlag) values (@componentName, @fileSize, @totalDownloads, @filePath, @price, @description, @disableFlag) I was inserting the decimal plainly without specification

Comment: it should be instead decimal(18,2), so the altered stored procedure is ,Create procedure [dbo].[NewComponentInsertion] (@componentName varchar(max), @fileSize decimal(18,2), @filePath varchar(max), @price decimal(18,2), @description varchar(max), @totalDownloads int, @disableFlag int) as insert into [dbo].[Components]([Component Name], [Size (in MB)],[Total Downloads], [FilePath], [Price (in SEK)], Description, DisableFlag) values (@componentName, @fileSize, @totalDownloads, @filePath, @price, @description, @disableFlag)

Comment: I see, so it was the parameter that was not declared correctly.  Same concept though.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the [SqlParameter.Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx) to 2.

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@fileSize", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter.Scale = 2;
parameter.Value = fileSizeInMBRounded;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Also look into `Precision` property as suggested by Bruno (default is 0).

Comment: as pointed out that was the error. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1):

You should set Scale and Precision.

I think that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter looks fine. I would check the data base column data type

Comment: You are right. Here is the mistake when i was inserting the data using the stored procedure,Create procedure [dbo].[NewComponentInsertion] (@componentName varchar(max), @fileSize decimal, @filePath varchar(max), @price decimal, @description varchar(max), @totalDownloads int, @disableFlag int) as
insert into [dbo].[Components]([Component Name], [Size (in MB)],[Total Downloads], [FilePath], [Price (in SEK)], Description, DisableFlag) values (@componentName, @fileSize, @totalDownloads, @filePath, @price, @description, @disableFlag) I was inserting the decimal plainly without specification